# Create multiple Relationships with For each

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I try to make relationships between an Outfit node and multiple Product nodes.
I am able to create a new Outfit node and then create Relationships between this node and the related product nodes. But is there a solution to no this in one query. My opinion is, that I have an array with the product Ids and then create a new outfit node, Match the node by ID for each value in the array and then create a relationship for each.

Do you have any suggestion? This is an example how it should look.

This is my approach, but there is an error with the where ID(a).

```
UNWIND keys({productIds:[1,2,3] }) AS key
Create (o:outfit {name: "Outfit für heute"})
FOREACH(item IN $list[key] 
| Merge(a:article) where ID(a) = item.productIds
| MERGE (o)-[r:includes]->(a)
)
```

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using `MERGE` for `article` instead of `MATCH`, and you cannot use `MATCH` within a `FOREACH`, also you are `UNWINDING` keys of a map, but you are not fetching that key value. It can be done simply like this, using `IN` operator:

```
Create (o:outfit {name: "Outfit für heute"})
WITH o
MATCH (a:article) where ID(a) IN [1, 2, 3]
MERGE (o)-[r:includes]->(a)
```

Comment: THANK YOU very much! I didn't know, that its not that easy!